# Ubuntu 18.04: Permission Denied:.ipynb_checkpoints when trying to create a new python3 notebook in jupyter

Tags: 18.04, firefox, python3, jupyter

I am starting jupyter notebook from the terminal, and am not using anaconda.

When I try to create a new python3 notebook I get this error message:

[image: screenshot of error]

I have tried the method in this link
[Cannot open new Jupyter notebook permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272880/cannot-open-new-jupyter-notebook-permission-denied)

However the issue still persists.

Answer (score 10):

You are in the home directory while creating a new python3 file on jupyter.
To avoid the error just click on any of the folders listed(documents or downloads etc) other than home, now try creating a new python file again. It will do.

Comment: you saved my time!!! Thanks!